# Performance: minimize database hitting

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `list<abbreviatedProducts>` that I need to cross-reference with values from my sql server 2008 database.

I am imagining I have to iterate the string and hit the database each time for each product.

```
List<string> abbreviatedProducts = new[] { strawb, bana, ki, orang };

for each (var item in products)
{
  //hit database to get full product name;
}
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: Hard to tell if it is the best way till at least you provide information what are requirements (i.e. caching may not be an option if data is very dynamic) and what you think is wrong with current approach.

Comment: We need more information: What ORM are you using? Are you using hand-rolled SQL Queries? How often do you hit this data? Can you use a caching mechanism? Does this data change often? What are the common use cases for accessing this data? Does it need to be absolutely up to date when accessed?

Comment: @Rod When you provide more information on the question (you can edit the question), I'll be happy to re-open it. As it currently stands, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

there is a quicker way, you can do:

```
List<string> products = new [] { "prod1", "prod2", "prod3" };

var dbProducts = datacontext.Products.Where(pr => products.Contains(pr.ProductName));
```

This assumes that you have a column in your `Products` table called `ProductName` which has names like "prod1" etc.

Comment: How this one would be quicker? I don't think product.Contains would be converted into SQL, so code is the same as Rod's...

Comment: but it is converted into SQL, that's why it is quicker

Comment: +1 may need to if result SQL statement works fine with your DB.

Comment: OP said c# and sql-server. If they are using LINQ to SQL, or LINQ to Entities then it will be absolutely fine.